# How to avoid reloading of controller while changing the parameter value of a route ?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing

Say, I have a route like: #/path/to/route/:dynamicParamter

Now whenever I click on a link where just that part is changing, angular loads the whole controller.
Is there a way I can avoid this and just let my controller to all UI changes based on URL without having to reload ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are ready to use `dynamicParamter` as a querystring parameter, then you can use the $routeProvider `reloadOnSearch` to false. See [$routeProvider documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/%24routeProvider).

In this case your `dynamicParameter` changes should only change the querystring parameter and the controller would not get loaded.

To know when the querystring change look at `$route#$routeUpdate` event.